# How to place an "inline image" in form before upload?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, file-upload

I want to allow users to write a post and upload images inline through out it (`like a CMS blog post`).

Writing the file upload script is easy.  But allowing a "place inline" button / functionality is proving to be tricky.
**Is there a tutorial on how to do this?**

I'm messing around with some JavaScript to allow it.  Also, I'm not sure if I should display the inline tmp image or actually upload the file (`with a separate upload button than the full form upload button`) and show the actual image loc before the form is submitted?  I'm all over the place on this right now.

**How should I go about this?**

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked how other websites do it? Stackoverflow has a nice way of handling images, but while writing, users only see the link to the image text in the textarea, not the actual image.

Comment: Why does it get complicated? I don't get it. Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: What i understood is you want to preview an image before its uploaded... If it is you can follow my answer :)

Comment: Either way it's fine.  I just want something functional right now.  What coding approach would be most efficient to do this?  I'm stuck on how to place it in an exact specified loc in the textarea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Add this HTML:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**Here is the preview: http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/edit#javascript,html,live**

I think it can help you.

Comment: Was there is something which you would like me to add or is there something i haven't understood?

Comment: Thanks, can you please break it down a little or explain what your doing in some detail?

Comment: As I said: where did you get this code from, how does it work, why does it work, how does it answer the OP's question?

Comment: Ok, that sounds great :| You can check the script here, what you need is practically done here [Click this active link](http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/edit#source)

Comment: That's a cool script.  But how can the user add it inline in a post.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to just show the image before you upload it.

Comment: @Graham Ok, you want to add the image in your post... your post content is in a textarea, right... and you want to add the image along with the content in the textarea... like in wordpress and joonla it use to do....

Comment: Actually, textareas contains text only, but you can overlap elements using a styled div instead of an image, but you can easily use an image instead of the div. [Check out this link](http://jsfiddle.net/2qMb3/1/)

Comment: So, this brings me to where I'm stuck.  Let's say I write 100 characters than decide to place an image inline in that spot.  How can that be done?

Comment: Use a div with contentEditable attribute which acts like a textarea. That's how wysiwyg editors are created.
[Checkout this example](http://jsfiddle.net/6bCRJ/)

Do one thing post a new question with reference to this question, so that other people can also suggest you some methods....

Answer (score 3):

You would use the HTML5 filereader: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#filereader-interface

A better working example, Copied from `http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/`

```
<style>
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }
  //trigger dom change after event
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: This one is cool, but it becomes annoying when somebody visits from a non-HTML5 supported browser... Still this is a great link, one up vote from my side :)